# Check for Ajax Request

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, httprequest

I've researched how to check if a request is sent via AJAX in C#, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. My code is below. I use a method to AJAX a page in clientside (in my case, the activeXobject is being used). The ajaxed page is checking the request of ajax properties serverside, but neither of the X-Requested-With properties return anything (I get blanks on print out). Ideas?

Ajax Method (Javascript)

```
/*
* Ajax page loads with url
* @param url : URL to call for ajax page load
* @param element : Element ID to be updated
*/
function ajax(url, element) {
    UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.INFO, "-AJAX Call for " + url + " in " + element + "-");
    var ajx;
    if (window.HXMLHttpRequest) {
        UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINE, "Using XMLHttpRequest");
        ajx = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINE, "Using ActiveXObject");
        ajx = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    ajx.open("GET", url, true);
    ajx.send();
    ajx.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajx.readyState == 4 && ajx.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = ajx.responseText;
        }
        else if (ajx.readyState == 4 && ajx.status == 400) {
            alert("Page Error. Please refresh and try again.");
        }
        else if (ajx.readyState == 4 && ajx.status == 500) {
            alert("Server Error. Please refresh and try again.");
        }
    }
    UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.INFO, "-END AJAX Call for " + url + " in " + element + "-");
}
```

Ajax Login Check (C#)

```
/* Checks for ajax request validity
 * @param HttpResponse resp : response to redirect if not ajax request
 * @param HttpRequest req : request to check for ajax
 */
public static void checkAjax(HttpResponse resp, HttpRequest req)
{
    if(req == null || 
        (req["X-Requested-With"] != "XMLHttpRequest" && 
        (req.Headers != null && req.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != "XMLHttpRequest"))){
           // resp.Redirect("./ajaxerror.aspx");
            resp.Write(req["X-Requested-With"] + ":" + req.Headers["X-Requested-With"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing something, but why are you checking for `if(req == null ||`? Shouldn't that be `if(req != null &&`? Again, maybe I'm just reading it wrong (I'm mostly a VB guy).

Comment: @Scott That's just a little extra check. If the request is null, there's an issue, so I go ahead and forward over to my ajax error page.

Comment: I see that that is commented out. I guess there was an else in there that you removed as well. Just saying b/c according to what you have there `if(req == null` goes into the `resp.Write(req["X-Requested-With"]...` portion of your code and would throw an error.

Comment: @Scott Oh, I see what you mean. Yeah the commented out resp.redirect is what will actually be used. The resp.write portion was just for some quick and dirty testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client side request doesn't provide any "X-Requested-With" header or query parameter to your server automatically (but some frameworks like Microsoft AJAX does). An AJAX call works like any HTTP request, to add some headers:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
```

Comment: So there is no native way to check for an AJAX request without setting the headers yourself?

Comment: An AJAX request will use the HTTP protocol without extra informations, the same way image, script or iframe are doing. if you want to track XHR request you have to "tag" it with an appropriate header (or parameter, cookie, ...)

Comment: Thanks. I've added the header information, and it's working fine now.